# Text aligning of TextBlock in listbox in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, textblock

I'm having a problem aligning the text in my listbox. I'm basically trying to create listbox that works like a uitableview in iOS.

In the code below the left TextBlock is set up just how I want it, but I can't get the right TextBlock to behave like I want it. Right now the text is right aligned so that when the text is too long to fit on the screen it cuts off the text at the beginning and just shows the end of the text. What I want to happen is have the TextBlock right aligned so that is stretches from the right but have the text inside of if left aligned so that it shows the beginning of the text and cuts off the end of the text.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStretchContentStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>


<ListBox Height="327" Margin="8,274,0,0" Name="myListBox" Width="442" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStretchContentStyle}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Title Text" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="cellTitle" />
                            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="This is some text that is too long to fit on the screen" HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextAlignment="Left" Padding="20,0,0,0" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

[`TextTrimming`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.texttrimming%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) might be of help here.
After setting the `TextWrapping="NoWrap"` could you try `TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"`. Then try, modifying the `TextAlignment`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could set the maxwidth parameter of the textblock to keep it from overlapping?

```
MaxWidth=""
```

Comment: This would work if the left TextBlock width was always the same but in my app they are all different. Is there a way to subtract the width of the left TextBlock from the ListBox width to get he size of the right TextBlock?